# Easy way to NAT compute engine instances

Tags: google-compute-engine

I assume the support for NAT is already available with the routing and networking available in compute engine? Looking for some easy to read documentation and commands to setup a situation where either one instance acts as a router and other instances can use that to access the public internet. Another scenario I'm looking for is how to make instances with no external IP address be able to access the internet. Is there a gcutil friendly way of scripting this up?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for the [Routes Collection](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/networking#routing).  For your first case, the examples should show you how one instance can act as a gateway for other instances by setting a route for the internal nodes to use the gateway as a "next hop" for their traffic.

For your second scenario, there is a [caveat](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/networking#routingpacketsinternet) listed that "Currently, any packets sent to the Internet must be sent by an instance that has an external IP address. If you create a route that sends packets to the Internet from a particular instance, that instance must also have an external IP. If you create a route that sends packets to the Internet gateway, but the source instance doesn't have an external IP address, the packet will be dropped."